# .toSorted() works only in a browser

Tags: javascript, browser

I am working on a LeetCode problem, I want to assign a variable to a sorted copy of an array.

```
sortedHeights = heights.toSorted()
```

However, this returns the following error `heights.toSorted is not a function`.
I looked up the issue on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSorted), and found the following code snippet:

```
const months = ["Mar", "Jan", "Feb", "Dec"];
const sortedMonths = months.toSorted();
console.log(sortedMonths); // ['Dec', 'Feb', 'Jan', 'Mar']
console.log(months); // ['Mar', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Dec']
```

I try to run this code snippet as well on WebStorm and I get the same error, however, when I run it in a browser it works. Why is that?

Comment: Works on only new browsers since it's very new. You can see the compatibility table on that MDN page.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`.toSorted()` is a new method. As you can see in the MDN doc you linked, it's not supported in node.js yet.

Answer (score 31):

At the time of this answer, [`Array.prototype.toSorted()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSorted) is supported by Node.js version 20+. Most developers use the Node.js LTS version (currently version 18). So if you're using Node.js version 19, 18 or lower in WebStorm, `.toSorted()` is not supported.

For the case of LeetCode, I see that [it currently uses Node.js 16](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) to run your code. So you might want to resort to this alternative (and effectively equivalent) code for the time being:

```
sortedHeights = [...heights].sort()
```

Also note that `.toSorted()` is currently supported in recent versions Chrome and Edge (from version 110), Safari (from version 16), Firefox (from version 115) and some other browsers, it's not supported in older versions - just in case you made an assumption that it works in all browsers.

Check the [Array.prototype.toSorted() MDN browser compatibility section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSorted#browser_compatibility) for latest support details.